# Check if StreamSubscription is canceled

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

To put it simple:

How do i check if a StreamSubscription is canceled?

There is no

```
_myCustomSub.isCanceled
```

Comment: Can you post a little more your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you'd have to use one of two methods:

1. [onDone method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-async/StreamSubscription/onDone.html) - and retain in a seperate variable whether the stream was closed, or..
2. [cancel method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.6.0/dart-async/StreamSubscription/cancel.html) - and `await` the future that signals that the StreamSubscription was canceled.

Don't know of any other way.

Comment: Hmm that's kinda sad. Thank you for your contribution nonetheless

Answer (score 3):

I've run into a similar situation and my solution was to make my StreamSubscription nullable and set it to null after cancel().

```
await _newAlertsStreamSubscription?.cancel().then((_) {
     _newAlertsStreamSubscription = null;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
final streamController = StreamController();
streamController.onCancel = (){};
```

According to the documentation: [Creating streams in Dart](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams)

[Waiting for a subscription](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#waiting-for-a-subscription)

> To be notified of subscriptions, specify an onListen argument when you
>   create the StreamController. The onListen callback is called when the
>   stream gets its first subscriber. If you specify an onCancel callback,
>   it’s called when the controller loses its last subscriber.

[Final hints](https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#final-hints)

> The onListen, onPause, onResume, and onCancel callbacks defined by
>   StreamController are called by the stream when the stream’s listener
>   state changes

In addition, this might be helpful:

```
//Whether there is a subscriber on the [Stream]
streamController.hasListener
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as others said, it's kinda lame that there is no way of checking if the stream subscription is canceled. I guess you don't have access to the `StreamController`, so here are my two options.

1. Set the `_myCustomSub` to `null` as a sign of canceled subscription and act accordingly.
2. Another way would be to have a `bool` value (`isSubCanceled`) somewhere together with the `_myCustomSub` variable, and use it instead of `_myCustomSub.isCanceled`.